# How do I publish an Uint8Array to IPFS, using its HTTP API on both browser and node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data, ipfs

I've been trying to do so for several hours to no success. The relevant API endpoint is [block/put](https://ipfs.io/docs/api/#api-v0-block-put). IT asks for the HTTP request to use `multipart/form-data`, but I'm not sure how to do it. Here is one attempt:

```
const req = require("xhr-request-promise");
const FormData = require("form-data");

(async () => {
  const form = new FormData();
  form.append("data", new Buffer([1, 2, 3]));
  console.log(await req("https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/block/put", {
    method: "POST",
    body: form
  }));
})();
```

Comment: What is issue with code at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 I get a `First argument must be a string or Buffer` error. I have no idea what that means (first argument of what, where?).

Comment: Does the api expect a `File` object? Not entirely clear from documentation what data is expected

Comment: Exactly. I'm confused and I have no idea how to use it properly (thus the question).

Comment: Are each of the arguments expected? For example, the  `curl` example `curl -F file=@myfile "http://localhost:5001/api/v0/block/put?format=v0&mhtype=sha2-256&mhlen=-1"` Have you considered filing an issue at https://github.com/ipfs/ipfs-http-api-docs/issues?

Comment: @guest271314 that is what I'm wondering. I'm not sure how to replicate that curl on both browser and node.js. Specifically the `-F` part is getting me. I don't know how to do it with the XHR lib, nor with the Axios lib, nor with plain XMLHttpRequest. I've read some and tried some things, but I keep getting errors such as `File argument 'data' is required`. It is probably a matter of getting a proper example.

Comment: Ask the authors and contributors of and to the api for clarification

Comment: @guest271314 I'll consider, but it is probably an issue on my side, no? I was assuming sending files that way was standard (after all, the curl works), I just don't know how to express that on browser/node.

Comment: Whether the issue is on your side or not, you should still be able to get clarification from the authors or contributors to github repository as to the correct procedure for the request that you are trying to make.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using `ipfs-http-client`? It's built for this task :). Edit: Ah maybe because it was 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ipfs-http-client](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/tree/master/packages/ipfs-http-client) is perfect for this task:

```js
const { create } = require('ipfs-http-client');

// connect to ipfs daemon API server
const ipfs = create('https://ipfs.infura.io:5001');

(async () => {
    await ipfs.block.put(new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3]));
})();
```